# Codeception Html Attributes Error Messages

Tags: phantomjs, codeception

I'm  working on a form field test, this test should check if an inputfield is not filled.

The inputfield has the required attribute like: `<input type="text" 
 required="required" >`

My problem is that the tag of Codeception `$I->see('errormessage');` does not recognize the message of the required tag. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
$I->seeInField($field, $value);
```

or:

```
$I->dontSeeInField($field, $value);
```

If you need reverse. Can't quite understand what you actually need to check but one of these methods should help you, just change $field and $value with your data.

Comment: its not actually a field, its like an pop-up, you know? 
example: you have an form where you need your name to register so the "name" is required, but you click on 'create account' without typing something in the namefield. Mostly there come a little popup, directly under/next to the input where the information is missing. Something like "You need to fill in a name to create an account" , this is not a popup via JS (where it would be more easy to check), its more directly by html itself, so I need an function to check this "Popup"

Comment: Then you go with $I->waitForElementVisible($element); just put right $element, give me html if you need help for that selector also. With element I mean actual popup which becomes visible after form submitting.

Comment: Hmmm, its not directly an element which pops up, its just the required tag of html...nothing more
nothing like: <input type="text" id="abc" >
where i could do:  $I->waitForElementVisible($element); abc = $element

i need something else, because its not a real element, i think...
here a link to the uploaded image of the error message: https://ibb.co/jsuWCQ

Comment: If you give me  html  structure of that input before and after that popup, I'll write you here actual assert that you need. So give me what changed in html. There must be change, just look at chrome developer tool. Or css change visible/unvisible...

Comment: i createt you an fiddle which gives the same error message (in firefox for e.g) which pops up: https://jsfiddle.net/LLs15a9z/
sorry i cannot give you the code of the website itself, but the problem in this fiddle is shown also

Comment: Ahaaa, I got you, it seems that nothings change in DOM. Can you try with:

$value = $I->grabValueFrom('#abc');

And than check  $I->assertNotEquals('', $value);

Comment: Ahhh now you got it! Thats what I tried to tell you^^

but $->assertNotEquals() is not shown as a function? is it a custom function?

Comment: Not custom, you have definition in _support/_generated/AcceptanceTesterActions.php. Here is from docs: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts#assertNotEquals

Comment: hmmm i got an undefined error message: 
https://ibb.co/maEL6k
https://ibb.co/cDvSmk

Comment: Then use workaround: $I->assertFalse('' == $I->grabValueFrom('#abc'));

Comment: still calling, undefined, is it maybe the problem that asserts has to be imported? (sorry normally I'm more in the react region, not php/codeception)
like an module?

Comment: maybe it's helpful, I use phantomJS as webdriver

Comment: Sry I forgot to tell you there is file acceptance.suite.yml inside of it you must load assert module. Here is my example:
 `modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://codeception.com/
            browser: phantomjs
            window_size: 1900x1400
        - Asserts
        - Db`

Comment: I can not paste in proper formatting here in comments but just load Assert module either in acceptance.suite.yml or main codeception.yml file, where ever you load modules.

Comment: i tried to import it in the AcceptanceTester.php like this: 
* @method \Codeception\Util\Shared\asserts assertFalse($condition, $message = '')

Comment: to keep it more easy? maybe skype?

Comment: Skypeid: milos12314